# Send decimal number with ExternalInterface between JS and AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I have problem with decimal numbers in ExternalInterface.
AS3 code:

```
var preview:Bitmap(loader.content);
var w:Number = preview.width;
var h:Number = preview.height;

trace(w, h) //In there I get values: 887.9 and 665.95.

ExternalInterface.call('test', w, h);
```

JS code:

```
function test(w, h)
{
     console.log(w, h); //And there I have values 0.95 and 0.7
}
```

Why? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: can you put an example page somewhwere on the web?

Comment: Have you tested with integer values? Have you tested with text? This would help narrow down the problem. If ints work and precision isn't critical then as a work around you could multiply by a large number in JS, round, pass, then divide again in AS

Comment: The ints and text are passing okey. And If I pass like this: ExternalInterface.call('test', 887.9, 665.95), are also good. But If the decimals is from variables w and h, then I got a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with Adobe example(http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary). I create a `Shape`(887.9, 665.95) in AS, and add a function as yours. It works well.

So, It may be influenced by something else.

For example, you can use `Shape` or other `DisplayObject` replace the Bitmap.